# How to draw a customize polar grid using Matlab

Tags: matlab

i would like to use Matlab for drawing a customize polar grid.

I.E: instead of setting X and Y direction in my grid as

```
X=r*cos(theta)
Y=r*sin(theta)
```

i want to set:

```
X=r;
Y=sin(theta)*X;
```

Can you please advise?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is embedded solution in Matlab to draw the polar grid on the plane:

[Matlab R2014b documentation - Polar coordinate plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polar.html)